# cookie disclaimer popup with http session?

Tags: c#, .net, session, cookies

Do i need a **cookie disclaimer** popup if i have a aspnet website with session state variables on server side and local storage of some variables on the client?

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise that you do if you are storing variables on the client side. This is just to avoid controversy later when someone finds that your site is storing things on their computer and they were not informed. In the end it is your decision.

Comment: Ok, thank you. But in case of session state variables on the server without local storage is it necessary?

Comment: I would not think so because it does not affect the clients machine.

Comment: How are you storing the SessionId? In a cookie? If so, that counts (even if it is the most inane, ridiculous law which often results in using a cookie to record the fact that the person knows about cookies)